Could not open cafile: ENOENT: no such file or directory
When I run all kinds of yarn commands like yarn dev/yarn add,it shows me this error message:

Could not open cafile: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Learn_MERN_STACK\with_HMNayem\Full-Stack-Army\Project\clean-youtube\https:\registry.yarnpkg.com'

I uninstalled the node and again install it, but I had to face the same type of error.
And some times it shows:
"error Could not open cafile: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\Learn_MERN_STACK\with_HMNayem\Full-Stack-Army\Project\clean-youtube\https:\registry.yarnpkg.com'
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild/darwin-arm64/-/darwin-arm64-0.20.2.tgz: read ECONNRESET
error https://registry.npmjs.org/@esbuild/darwin-x64/-/darwin-x64-0.20.2.tgz: read ECONNRESET
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 41.82s."

package.json
{
  "name": "clean-youtube",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^5.0.12",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.15",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.15",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^6.0.0-alpha.18",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "easy-peasy": "^6.0.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.55",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "vite": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "description": "This template provides a minimal setup to get React working in Vite with HMR and some ESLin`your text`t rules.",
  "main": "vite.config.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/nurhossainfarid/clean-youtube.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nurhossainfarid/clean-youtube/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/nurhossainfarid/clean-youtube#readme"
}


Do you happen to have a .yarnrc, .yarnrc.yml or .npmrc file present in the project directory or your home directory?
